# Como verificar as constraints no banco

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Olá, como verifico se minhas constraints estão ligadas no banco inteiro? Preciso de uma query para Oracle e SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso para ver todas as constraints:

```
select * from information_schema.referential_constraints
where constraint_schema = 'NOME_DO_SEU_BANCO'
```

Para SQL Server, tem mais informações aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

E para o Oracle tente isso, substituindo os valores:

```
select R.TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE U
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS FK
    on U.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    and U.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE R
    ON R.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    AND R.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE U.COLUMN_NAME = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  AND U.TABLE_CATALOG = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
  AND U.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cccccccccccc'
  AND U.TABLE_NAME = 'ddddddddddddd'
```